# Input labels and long names

Tags: css

I've made these forms that keeps the label visible after its filled. I use absolute positioning, which gives the issue that the padding-left is a fixed distance, that doesn't depend on the length of the labelname.
You can see the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/eo4uop7g/

I've tried to figure out some other solutions but without any luck. Maybe some of you got an idea how to make this more flexible?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').each(function() {

    $(this).on('focus', function() {
      $(this).parent('.userbasic article').addClass('active');
    });

    $(this).on('blur', function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).parent('.userbasic article').removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).parent('.userbasic article').addClass('active');

  });

});
```

```css
form input {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: .1s all linear;
}

.userbasic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.userbasic article {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.userbasic article:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.userbasic article:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.userbasic article.active input {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
.userbasic article.active label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 18px;
  color: white;
  background: #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.userbasic label {
  position: absolute;
  color: #777;
  top: 18px;
  left: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: .1s all linear;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="userbasic">
  <article>
    <label for="i4">Zip</label>
    <input id="i4" type="text">
  </article>
  <article>
    <label for="i5">Very long name</label>
    <input id="i5" type="Number">
  </article>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using absolute positioning use static/relative position for label and use flex to position label next to input field. That way your label will shrink input when text is longer

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').each(function() {

    $(this).on('focus', function() {
      $(this).parent('.userbasic article').addClass('active');
    });

    $(this).on('blur', function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).parent('.userbasic article').removeClass('active');
      }
    });

    if ($(this).val() != '') $(this).parent('.userbasic article').addClass('active');

  });

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form input {
  height: 45px;
  flex: 1;
  transition: 100ms all linear;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-left: none;
}
.userbasic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.userbasic article {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 .5rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.userbasic article:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.userbasic article:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.userbasic article.active label {
  color: white;
  background: #777;
}
.userbasic label {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: 100ms all linear;
  cursor: text;
  height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-right: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="userbasic">
  <article>
    <label for="i4">Zip</label>
    <input id="i4" type="text">
  </article>
  <article>
    <label for="i5">Very long name</label>
    <input id="i5" type="Number">
  </article>
</form>
```